# Solr Security : authentication/authorization Not recognized

Tags: security, solr, warnings

I am currently working on Solr in Standalone Mode.
Since I'm a beginner on Solr I wanted to start the server with the command start -e techproducts.
The core is well uploaded but a warning message appears:
"Not all security plugins configured! authentication= disabled authorization = disabled. Solr is only as secure as you make it. Considere configuring authentication/authorization before  exposing solr to users internal or external"

The problem is that I have already created my security.json, I have put it in the home directory and I have authenticated myself at the server entrance, so it's seems efficient. Why does this warning message keep appearing?

[image: picture of the warning message]

Comment: Please include relevant information as text in your question, as text in images has rather low accessibility. Please include any relevant configuration you've done as well; if the server asks for authentication _for any endpoint_, including querying the data, then it seems like the error message is wrong (.. and which version of Solr?) - but I'm guessing it's because there are endpoints that aren't protected.

Comment: Sorrry, i forget to put a description but the image of the warning message is in the link :) the server asked me for authentication but it doesn't mention endpoint.

Comment: Is it possible that the warning is old and not applicable anymore? If you restart Solr, do you get the warning again (with a new date and time) ?

Comment: Well, I try to restart Solr and the same warning msg appears

Comment: Having a description doesn't help anyone that's searching for the error message or people who have trouble seeing. Text should be added to the question properly, so that it's both accessible and searchable.

Comment: Yes you right, i added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing the `security.json` file in the proper place, so that Solr can read during startup.

Visit the [Dashboard](http://localhost:8983/solr/#/) page and look for the `solr.solr.home` property which should look like this: `-Dsolr.solr.home=/var/solr/data`, then you write the  file to `/var/solr/data/security.json`. Then restart Solr and during startup the console should show something like thi instead of the WARN:

```
INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Initializing authorization plugin: solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin
INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Initializing authentication plugin: solr.BasicAuthPlugin
```